# How can Tesla Model S accelerate quicker than it can decelarate?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, friction

According to Motor Trend, Tesla Model S Plaid needs less distance to get from 0 to 60 mph, than to stop from 60.

> Sixty mph arrives in the aforementioned 1.98 seconds, and the car is still pulling 1.11 g—and is >just 98 feet from where it started. Yes, the entire sub-2.0-second drama occurs in less than 100 >feet.
> Interestingly, on regular asphalt, the car needs 104 feet and 2.38 seconds to stop from 60 mph, >averaging 1.16 g in the opposite direction. We don't dive into detail like this often, but this >might be another first: a car that accelerates from 0-60 mph in a shorter time and distance than >it achieves 60-0 mph.

Link to the article:
https://www.motortrend.com/features/tesla-model-s-plaid-test-data-analysis-milestones-records/

How is this possible? I guess that every car is traction-limited on braking (i.e. brakes are stronger than available friction of tires). Model S is, I guess, first road car that can accelerate as hard as it can brake, thanks to it's immensely powerful motors. But, how is more traction available for acceleration, than for braking?

Comment: This question is about engineering.

Comment: Have you considered that the method to propel the car and to stop the car are different? One requires the motor turn the wheels, while the other requires a breaking mechanism which is usually friction and/or magnetically based.

Comment: IMO not really physics or engineering, just philosophy of use. The number of people who would be seriously inconvenienced by their vehicle skidding for a moment while holding down the accelerator is considerably smaller than the number of people who would be seriously inconvenienced by their vehicle skidding for a moment while slamming on the brakes, so if you have to balance maximum acceleration and probability of a skid, you're going to bias towards acceleration while speeding up and bias towards not skidding while slowing down.

Comment: How do they get 1.11g for the acceleration which is less than 1.16g for the braking? I'm too lazy to calculate this in the weird units (instead of feet, I'd prefer nanolightseconds) but something is a bit odd here.

Comment: It is physics insofar as the accelerating force (+ve and -ve) is limited by the friction of the wheels. So if the engine and brakes are engineered to the physical limit, why is there a difference? The difference however does seem very small, so I wonder if it is just an artefact as no road will be perfectly uniform and they may have tried the acceleration on a road section with a bit more traction.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen read the quote again. The average acceleration while speeding up is never stated (although it's trivial to calculate), only the acceleration at t=1.98s.

Comment: @gs Ah, thanks, I'm not used to such texts that just throw out random numbers that can't be compared. And calculating acceleration is indeed trivial in principle, but I'd have to look up what the antiquated units feet and mph are in real units, and that's not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

The working capacity of a brake is rated in horsepower, and for cheap compact cars the brakes almost always have a higher rating than the engine does- which means you can stop the car from a given speed quicker than you can accelerate from zero to that speed.

But the tesla designers wanted to wow the world with a car that was capable of tremendous acceleration (0-to-60 being a standard benchmark). So they put motors and batteries in that furnished a world-beating acceleration time, and got it.